# Android retrofit @GET parameters

Tags: android, json, get, gson, retrofit

i have this interface for getting weather (from openweather API) for city RZESZOW and country POLAND, how can i query params? I need to get city name and country from user and get data

```
public interface RestInterface {

@GET("/weather?q=rzeszow,pl&appid=527f7a1296bd7b0f21e47fc01a982087")
void getWheatherReport(Callback<Model> cb);
```

}

Here i call it

```
  //making object of RestAdapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(url).build();

    //Creating Rest Services
    RestInterface restInterface = adapter.create(RestInterface.class);

    //Calling method to get whether report
    restInterface.getWheatherReport(new Callback<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Model model, Response response) {
STUFF HERE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>.........<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
```

where can I learn more about Retrofit, APIS, JSON etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass parameters you can use `@Query`.

In your case

```
@GET("/weather")
void getWheatherReport(@Query("q") String place, @Query("appid") String appId, Callback<Model> cb);
```

You can read more here - [enter link description here](http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks i solve it like: 

 @GET("/weather?appid=527f7a1296bd7b0f21e47fc01a982087")
 //   void getWheatherReport(Callback<Model> cb);
       void getName(@Query("q")String name, Callback<Model> cb);

thanks!